# How to get number of Instagram followers on a specified date like minter.io does?

Tags: api, statistics, instagram, analytics, instagram-api

[image]

From the picture, you can see how followers statistics looks on [minter.io](http://minter.io)

The only way how I imagine I would count the followers change: I would download the list of all he followers every day by the Instagram API to my DB. And after having this history already can calculate any change.

But on [minter.io](http://minter.io) you can have such a graphics after few minutes after registration... How???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are probably storing this information on a daily basis and hence are able to keep a historical trend.

If you go to the minter.io website, they mention at the bottom that they have collected data for close to 198 million accounts. I guess you were one of those.

You don't need to get the list of all followers just to show the absolute change in the numbers. The Instagram API gives that directly when you query any of the endpoints giving user information.

Comment: Interesting version. Can you be more certain, please, about of getting of the absolute change you mentioned?

Comment: The absolute change will be possible if you track a profile for two consecutive days. That is probably how minter.io is doing it. From what I can gather, they are just showing the change in number, which can be done once you have timeseries data.

Answer (score 1):

I know how it works at [smartmetrics.co](https://smartmetrics.co).
Smartmetrics collects information about all followers of tracked accounts and build history based on this data. So if you followed someone who is already tracked, you can get history for your account.

But minter makes fake linear graph according to some tests: [How to Get Historical Data from Instagram API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34033645/how-to-get-historical-data-from-instagram-api)

Answer (score 0):

Crowdbabble and Minter re-use Twitter tokens, which allows them to collect data on millions of accounts. This gives you the historical data that you want -- change in followers over time. As an individual, you aren't able to access the Twitter API and aggregate data like that for storage as easily. You don't have thousands of people giving you tokens that you can then scrape and store on a regular basis.

Crowdbabble has a free 14 day trial with no payment info required. If you don't want in-depth analytics, Twittercounter will give you your follower numbers over the past 30 days -- you can view each day separately.