# Missing Connected Instagram Account Fields for Pages in Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram

I am trying to get our users Facebook Pages with connected Instagram Business Accounts using the API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me/accounts?fields=id,name,connected_instagram_account{ig_id,name}&limit=20
```

For some pages, I did not get the connected Instagram Accounts.

We have tried to set up again (ie. by removing the linked facebook page and then link it from Instagram Settings), but I am not able to get the connected instagram accounts info yet.

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: hard to say for third party developers. you may need to file a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Prerequisite: You first need the business Instagram account to be linked with Facebook Page. https://help.instagram.com/356902681064399 - That one can do from the profile page of Instagram account.

Currently, for FaceBook graph API we need a linked business page to Instagram account. As above APIs uses page tokens.

[Please Look into this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46635195/how-to-access-instagram-feed-of-any-user-with-new-graph-api)

Comment: Hi D-john Anshani, I already have linked the Business Account with a Facebook Page while converting the personal profile to business profile and also I tried to unlink the page and link the same again to make sure that the page is linked properly with the Instagram business account(for some users, we tried this and it worked out well).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Resolved it by following these steps :

1. Unlink your account from Facebook page.
2. Go to your Instagram app and login to your account.
3. Go to the settings page.
4. Scroll down to Business Settings and find "Switch back to personal account" and click on that.

> Note : On Doing so, you will lose your media insights.

5. Again setup your business profile for Instagram.
6. Come back to facebook business page and link your Instagram account.
7. Use the Graph API Explorer to get instagram_bussiness_account

Detailed answer here : [Instagram Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007928/instagram-graph-api/52216857#52216857)

Comment: OP already said *we have tried to set up again ie. by removing the linked facebook page and then link it from Instagram Settings)*.

Comment: Removing linked Facebook page and converting Instagram profile to personal. Not linking from there, as I mentioned in the answer too. In Instagram settings you will find the option "Switch back to personal account".. You will have to use that .. and then again setup a business profile for Instagram and then relink with your Facebook page.

Comment: can you make it clearer in your answer what the difference is to already given answer?

Comment: Hey @colidyre have done so, did not care to elaborate much previously as I had given a link to detailed answer there.

Comment: I had this not working and the reset fixed it but i created a new business account instead of converting an existing one maybe that's why it worked.